# C# sockets missing some data unless I set a breakpoint

Tags: c#, sockets

I am troubleshooting an issue on a relatively simple socket application which is listening for status updates from a third party machine. I have set up a TcpListener object to wait for a connection request and then establish the socket to read the data coming in. I get the periodic heartbeat as expected without issue, but whenever there is a sudden change in status the server machine sends out an immediate update which I don't get. The bizarre thing here is that I get the update no problem if I set a breakpoint in the code.

The server itself handles these connections a little strangely and doesn't maintain an open socket connection. when it tries to send data, it opens the connection, sends data, and then closes the connection, which is why I've built this to similarly wait for a connection and close it when the data transfer is done before beginning to listen for another connection request.

```
private void ListeningThread()
    {
        bool keep_going = CreateConnection();

        CreateTimer();

        while (keep_going)
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_ThreadShutdownEvent.IsSet)
                {
                    // event was set, so shut down
                    keep_going = false;
                    m_Listener.Stop();

                    bool appshuttingdown = false;

                    DestroyTimer();

                    lock (m_Lock)
                    {
                        appshuttingdown = m_ApplicationShutDown;
                    }

                    if (!appshuttingdown)
                    {
                        RunStatusNotification();
                    }

                    Connected = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (m_Listener.Pending())
                    {
                        Socket socket = m_Listener.AcceptSocket();

                        if (socket != null)
                        {
                            StateObject state = new StateObject();
                            state.Socket = socket;

                            try
                            {
                                int bytes_read = socket.Receive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None);
                                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                if (bytes_read == 14)
                                {
                                    if (state.Buffer.Count() > 13)
                                    {
                                        int packet = state.Buffer[13];
                                        InterpretRelevantByte(packet, now);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                FireUnknownException(ex);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                socket.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_Logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the break point? Also how and where is m_ThreadShutdownEvent.IsSet set?

Comment: I've been setting the breakpoint where I call m_Listener.AcceptSocket.
The shutdownEvent is set when a Stop method is called to signal the app is closing.

Comment: That sounds like it could possibly be a race condition/timing issue. Have you tried following m_Listener.AcceptSocket with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)? Of course that's not a good idea for production code, but it would tell you if there's something you need to be waiting for, then you could figure out what.

Comment: Never mind, first you want to look at that bytes_read thing @SpaceghostAli just brought up.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I suspected a race condition of some kind but was having a hard time figuring out how to proceed. It looks like adding that sleep is fixing the problem so I'll investigate further.

Comment: @AJAX86 So is the other machine sending out two separate messages? One a regular status, and then (potentially, depending on most recent status) an update immediately thereafter? In that case you'd want to look at the status message, and if it indicates that you should expect a second message, block while waiting for more bytes (or drop back into the wait loop, with a flag or something). But I may misunderstand you.

Comment: the other machine sends out only one message: a string of bytes that contain it's status. It sends this out on a regular interval, but if at any time the status changes, it will immediately resend out it's message with the updated status byte. for whatever reason, I am not getting the message it sends on a status change unless I add in a small thread.sleep delay, or insert a break point.

Comment: So is it like send a message, wait a minute, send a message, status changes after 13 seconds so send an extra message right then, send next every-minute message 47 seconds later, wait a minute, send a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved this. Turns out I was closing the socket too soon which led to some weird behavior that, honestly, I don't fully understand, but I do know how I fixed it.

After opening the socket I needed to continue listening for data until receiving a 0 length message which signaled that the server had closed the connection. At that point I could start listening for a new socket connection request. I'm still not sure why I would get the heartbeats only, but everything has been working perfectly since I made the change.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your call to receive gets you some value greater than or less than 14, you should probably add some logic to inspect the data you receive when bytes read is not equal to 14 since in these cases you are discarding what you've read.

```
int bytes_read = socket.Receive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None);
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

if (bytes_read == 14)
{
    if (state.Buffer.Count() > 13)
    {
        int packet = state.Buffer[13];
        InterpretRelevantByte(packet, now);
    }
}
else if (bytes_read > 14)
{
    // maybe you received multiple messages in one packet
}
else
{
    // maybe there is more data on the way
}
```

Comment: Agreed that that code is a little problematic, however, those extra conditionals are never hit when I add them.